# Python Help - Encoding and Decoding Using ORD and CHR (ASCII)

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

So I'm teaching myself to code, and I'm doing the challenge where you use ord and chr to encode and decode messages with ASCII. I stumbled onto this code (below) on another question, and was wondering if there was an easy way to convert it to decode, rather than encode? :-)

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(raw_input("Please enter shift: "))
result = ""

for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    result += chr(x + shift)

print result
```

Comment: All this does is add a shift to the ciphertext input. You cannot imagine what the inverse operation looks like? If `'a'` is 97, and you can decode it with a shift of `10`, the ciphertext for that character would have to be as 87. How would you go about *producing* that ciphertext?

Comment: In other words, this is not a programming problem, you can solve it with math instead. (Hint, the inverse of `+` is `-`).